Problem with converting Data from Excel in Python
I have problem with converting data to float when reading excel with pandas. Here are the data in Excel (report from SAP):
      6.321,68
44,33
40
540,44

excel file image 
python is reading data like this:
0          6.321,68
1             44.33
2                40
3            540.44
Name: AmortSAP, dtype: object

My goal is to convert these data to float as follows:
0           6321.68
1             44.33
2                40
3            540.44

I will be grateful for any form of help!
Best regards, Maciej!

# I try to use code like below, however as you can see it doesn't work well.

import pandas as pd
import pyodbc
import sqlalchemy

#import Excel file and skip specific columns
file = 'AmortSAP.xlsx'
use_cols = [8]

df = pd.read_excel(file, usecols = use_cols, skiprows= 10, names = ['AmortSAP'], dtype= 'str', engine = 'openpyxl')
print(df['AmortSAP'])

df['AmortSAP'] = df['AmortSAP'].str.replace(" ","")
df['AmortSAP'] = df['AmortSAP'].str.replace(",","")
df['AmortSAP'] = df['AmortSAP'].astype(float)

print(df['AmortSAP'])

#before changes
0          6.321,68
1             44.33
2                40
3            540.44

#after changes
0      6.32168
1     44.33000
2     40.00000
3    540.44000

I try as you can see above, but the number on line "0" is obviously incorrect.
It should be  6321.68 instead of  6.32168.

How do we reproduce your issue?

Sorry, could you elaborate or tell me what is unclear in my question?

I want to run a test case on my computer that will reproduce your issue, then I can try to fix it for you. You need to provide complete working code that I can use to to that. As it stands now, I don't have your Excel file.

What happens when you just df = pd.read_excel(file)

thank you for tips. I have just passed all code.

i also add picture of my excel "excel file image"

ok the problem solved.

1
If i am reading from excel , i can use the decimal and thousands parameters:
df = pd.read_excel(..., decimal=',', thousands='.')
